# Joining DataTables in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I am new to C# and .net. Here is my problem

i have two DataTables, each having just one column

```
dtTab1 - 
          col1 
           a    
           c    

dtTab2 - 
          col2
           p
           q
```

now i want to merge these into a result table that should look like this

```
dtResult - col1 col2 
           a    p    
           c    q
```

i tried

```
dtResult.Merge(dtTab1, false, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
dtResult.Merge(dtTab2, false, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
```

but for some reason it creates 4 rows instead of two.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in application code and not in the database command that populates the table?

Comment: One of the problems that I can see with this simplistic approach is you're not telling the application how to relate the values in dtTab1 to dtTab2.  You say "put these tables together" and in your head it may be obvious that you want the first row in dtResult to contain two columns, col1 and col2, using the col1 value from the first row in dtTab1 and the col2 value from the first row in dtTab2, but although this seems obvious to you, you have to define all those relationships and rules for the application.

Comment: Thanks Mason, unfortunately, i have to do this in application code due to the nature of the project

Comment: Thanks Francine, you are right. Since i am new to the syntax i am having trouble expressing the code. If possible, could you please provide a sample ? Would it make sense for me to store the data in say a 2-d array first and then create rows for my result table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help. Tim's solution got me closest to the answer but here's how i finally managed to solve it

```
    DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
    DataColumn col = null;
    string ColName = string.Empty;
    int i;
    int ColCnt = 1;

    dtResult.Clear();
    dtResult.Columns.Clear();

    for (i = 0; i < dtTab1.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        ColName = dtTab1.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        col = new DataColumn(ColName);
        col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        dtResult.Columns.Add(col);
        ColCnt++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < dtTab2.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        ColName = dtTab2.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        col = new DataColumn(ColName);
        col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        dtResult.Columns.Add(col);
        ColCnt++;
    }


        object[] elems = new object[dtTab1.Columns.Count + dtTab2.Columns.Count];

        for (int r = 0; r < Math.Min(dtTab1.Rows.Count, dtTab2.Rows.Count); r++)
        {
            DataRow r1 = dtTab1.Rows[r];
            DataRow r2 = dtTab2.Rows[r];
            DataRow row ;

            int q = 0;
            for (; q < dtTab1.Columns.Count; q++)

                elems[q] = r1.ItemArray[q];


            int z = 0;
            for (; z < dtTab2.Columns.Count; z++)

                elems[q + z] = r2.ItemArray[z];


            row = dtResult.NewRow();
            row.ItemArray = elems;
            dtResult.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Tim, your solution really helped me understand the flow, but for some reason i was getting an ArgumentException at

```
row.SetField(col.ColumnName, r1[col]);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the right data type in your target table?  Use this: col.DataType = dtTab1.Columns[i].DataType;  (instead of col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");)

Comment: Thanks Francine, you are right i should be using your approach. for this case i knew what the data type was going to be but going forward i should do as you have suggested.

Answer (score 4):

There is no relation defined between the tables, so `Merge` just concats them.

You could add them manually:

```
DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
foreach (DataColumn col in dtTab1.Columns)
    dtResult.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);
foreach (DataColumn col in dtTab2.Columns)
    dtResult.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);

for (int r = 0; r < Math.Min(dtTab1.Rows.Count, dtTab2.Rows.Count); r++)
{
    DataRow r1 = dtTab1.Rows[r];
    DataRow r2 = dtTab2.Rows[r];
    DataRow row = dtResult.Rows.Add();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dtTab1.Columns)
        row.SetField(col.ColumnName, r1[col]);
    foreach (DataColumn col in dtTab2.Columns)
        row.SetField(col.ColumnName, r2[col]);
}
```

Comment: Nice one. If you want, you can shorten your code with `dtResult = dtTab1.Copy()`. Then, you only have to add columns and data from `dtTab2`.

Comment: @Heinzi: is not really shorter, so i wanted to keep it consistent between both tables to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There's no relationship between tables, but it's possible to join them based on index.

Try it:

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("col1", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt1.Columns.Add(dc);
dt1.Rows.Add(new Object[]{"a"});    
dt1.Rows.Add(new Object[]{"c"});

DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dc = new DataColumn("col2", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt2.Columns.Add(dc);
dt2.Rows.Add(new Object[]{"p"});    
dt2.Rows.Add(new Object[]{"q"});

DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
dc = new DataColumn("index", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
dtResult.Columns.Add(dc);
dc = new DataColumn("col1", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dtResult.Columns.Add(dc);
dc = new DataColumn("col2", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dtResult.Columns.Add(dc);

var dtRows = from r1 in dt1.AsEnumerable().Select((x,y)=>new{col1 = x.Field<string>("col1"), index = y})
        join r2 in dt2.AsEnumerable().Select((x,y)=>new{col2 = x.Field<string>("col2"), index = y}) on r1.index equals r2.index
        select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new Object[]{r1.index, r1.col1, r2.col2}, true);
dtRows.CopyToDataTable();
dtResult.Dump();
```

Note: above code has been created in LinqPad.

Result:

```
index col1 col2
0     a    p 
1     c    q
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rather more compact (and simpler) version that should do what you want.

```
        DataTable result = new DataTable();
        result.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(object));
        result.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(object));

        // assuming both data tables have the same length
        for (int row = 0; row < dtTab1.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            DataRow dr;
            dr = result.NewRow();
            dr[0] = dtTab1.Rows[row][0];
            dr[1] = dtTab2.Rows[row][0];
            result.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

You can adjust result.Columns.Add to create the table with the column Db types that your table requires.

```
result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col2", Type.GetType("System.String")));
```